# showing inline or embedded images of a mail body in jsp web page

Tags: jakarta-mail, inline, email-attachments

I am polling an exchange server and reading mails from that, saving mail details like To, From , body i.e. either HTML source code or text/plain in database. Body source code I am showing in content editable div in presentation layer and hence mails are being displayed perfectly as in Outlook or Lotus Notes. **But I am facing problem with embedded / inline images. As within html source code it is coming as cid:Image01.. hence I am not getting the actual path of images from where I can show that in DIV.** Attachments coming as separate attachment but not showing within mail body.

Any idea of doing it? Would be better if any sample java code can be provided. I am not sure about the mechanism, how Outlook or Lotus Notes as a client are able to show those inline images?

Regards
Soumya

Answer (score 0):

You need to process the html content and convert the cid: references into http: references to some URL that your application will use to fetch the corresponding part of the message.